# PROAIM BMP60 thoughts

Tags: budget, blimp

Hi guys,

For a budget priced blimp, has anyone had experience with the Proaim BMP60 R or S?

Noticed it has been mentioned in a post before, though cannot find any buyer reviews except for a the  (unsurprisingly) glowing reports on the company's site.

For its price range, woudl you recommend it?

And the difference between the R and S model looks to be only the handle and a $30 difference in price, any thoughts on the R being worth the extra $30 for a covered handle?

Beaks

Comment: I'm also curious on the responses

Comment: I ordered a Proaim BMP60 R Blimp type. Soon, I'll explain my experiences.

Answer (score 1):

It's completed as i promised :) .I hope i can help you with my video.

Comment: Hi there.  How are you finding it?  Overall I'm quite happy, although I find the rubber bands for the shock mount too loose, especially when I use longer mics and install a battery in them.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I bought one of them and the suspension is bad (It is noisy... the rubber), but the cage and fur work pretty well.  What I've done ?  I just bought 2 spares "universal Lyre 72" suspensions from Rycote and I put them in place of the regular ones.  I paid 20€ for the Rycote Lyre pair, and now, I have a very good blimp for a very cheap price !
Enjoy this tip !  ;)
Jef Guay